# Nodejs: Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

This node/express function is giving me an error:
Can't set headers after they are sent.
it used to work fine, but i have made some changes to the user schema, moving all address items to be under 'address', like this:

```html
firstname,
lastname,
address:{
   street,
   city,
   loc (array of numbers)
   ...
}
```

so the new function looks like this:

```html
export function searchMembers(req, res) {
  var lat = req.body.lat;
  var lon = req.body.lon;
  var zoom = req.body.zoom || 14;
 
  var query = User.find();
 var distance = 5000;

 // when this line is removed, problem is gone:
 query = query.where('address.loc').near({center:{type:'Point', coordinates:[lon,lat]}, maxDistance: distance, spherical:true});
 query = query.where({'address.city': 'Toronto'}); 
 query = query.sort({'lastname': 1});
     
    query.exec(function(err,users){
         if(err) res.send(err);
 
          var final = [];
          _.forEach(users, function(x){
            var obj = {};
            obj.id = x._id;
            obj.name=x.firstname + ' ' + x.lastname;
            obj.latitude=x.address.loc[1] ;
            obj.longitude=x.address.loc[0] ;

            final.push(obj);
          });
          res.status(200).json(final);
      });
}
```

So when i run this, i get the funny error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
pointing to the last line in the function: 
res.status(200).json(final);

i tried to eliminate stuff to find the root cause.
when i remove the where line with the 'near' function, the problem is gone.
i have added other filtering, just for testing, everything fine. only this one is causing an issue. 
Any idea?

Comment: Can you try to change your error handling to `if (err) return res.send(err)`? My guess it that an error gets thrown, `res.send` gets called, and after that, the final `res.status` at the bottom gets called, too, resulting in your error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error means, that you already used method `res.json()/render()/send()` and you try to do it again.

In your case, this line does not stop method from executing  `if(err) res.send(err);`

You have to write return to stop it.

```
if(err) {
    res.send(err);
    return;
}
```

Which is equivalent to

```
if(err) {
    return res.send(err);
}
```

Just do not think about it as returning "res.send(err)", it is using res.send(err) and after that using return to stop executing.

---

The reason why removing line also removes error :

You have some error in that line (like having bad column names), therefore in callback the error is send and then you use `res.send(err)` and after that you call `res.status(200).json(final)`

Comment: you have saved my day. your answer is correct, and when i changed the error function to your version, i got back the error, which is index not found for geo search. and indeed i forgot to add that index. Thank you!